# Does canDisplayBannerAds only use a single instance of an iAd Banner?

Tags: ios, ios8, iad, adbannerview

I am creating an iOS8 application and started to implement iAd's Banner in code, but yesterday I discovered that I can use the `canDisplayBannerAds` property. I enabled it on each of the views in my application, and it is working.  Previously, when I was implementing it with my own code, there was a lot of discussion about the importance of using a singleton of the `ADBannerView`.  Does `canDisplayBannerAds` use a singleton, or is it violating what I had read about the importance of using a singleton?  Does it really matter from a performance, advertising, and Apple Store perspective?

Thank you for your comments and feedback,

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it uses a new one each time. I ran into that problem when first using iAd. Each vc had canDisplay... And the ads got all messed up. In fact they didn't even show up in the App Store version. Best to use either the singleton method or something similar that reuses the iAd. I myself use the app delegate. All my apps use that and I have not run into any problems at all. Good luck!

EDIT#1

Here is a [link](http://thefizixgroup.blogspot.com/p/iad-implementation_6.html) to a blog post I wrote using iAd with the app delegate.  It is written in Objective-C but at least you will get the general idea.  I basically create an iAd banner in the app delegate and then use that one in every vc you need.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, Douglas!@  Somehow I knew that using canDisplay...  would be too simple!  So, the only reason for it to exist is for a single view app, I suppose...  The reason that I wanted to use it is that I was having a lot of trouble getting the bannerview to size appropriately on iOS8 using autolayout and playing with constraints.  At one point, I thought about switching to iOS9 so I could use the stackview! I will return to my original work and look at the links that you've recommended.  I suspect that I will be posting about the sizing issue, soon. :P  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hey Downvoter, how about some explanation so I can improve my answer?!?!

Comment: Hi Douglas,  Actually, I don't know how it downvoted...  Can you please tell me how to fix it?

Comment: A Bit of Help , Just click the up arrow above the -1.  But I am glad to help!

Comment: Hmmm... I just watched the WWDC 2015 video on iAd, and they seem to promote simply enabling canDisplayBannerAds in each view.  I wonder whether they have resolved the issues with having multiple instances of ADBanner, internally.  Is there an easy way to determine whether this is still an issue?

Comment: Not sure how to check. I know before they wanted to have only one instance. They may have updated it. I will look into that video too. Thanks.